# using two search and replace regex commands in Perl

Tags: perl

In a file, I have to replace

```
.L1 to L_xx_1 
.L2 to L_xx_2 
.L3 to L_xx_3 
...
```

and

```
.LC1 to LC_xx_1
.LC2 to Lc_xx_2
.LC3 to LC_xx_3
...
```

For these two search and replacements I have two different Perl scripts containing following two different loops:

```
for ($i=0; $currentLine=<file>; $i++) {
    $currentLine =~ s/.L(\d+)/L_$ARGV[1]_$1/gi;
    print $currentLine;
}
```

and

```
for ($i=0; $currentLine=<file>; $i++) {
     $currentLine =~ s/.LC(\d+)/LC_$ARGV[1]_$1/gi;
     print $currentLine; 
}
```

respectively.

Can I merge these two loops into one by merging two S commands into one.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can combine the 2 substitutions into one with a different regular expression.  You can capture the "L" followed by an optional "C".

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $str = 'xx';
while (my $currentLine = <DATA>) {
    $currentLine =~ s/\.(LC?)(\d+)/$1_${str}_$2/gi;
    print $currentLine;
}

__DATA__
.L1
.L2
.L3
.LC1
.LC2
.LC3
```

This prints:

```
L_xx_1
L_xx_2
L_xx_3
LC_xx_1
LC_xx_2
LC_xx_3
```

Note that I escaped the first character (the period).  This will only match a literal period.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your regex to 
`$currentLine =~ s/\.L(C?)(\d+)/L$1_$ARGV[1]_$2/gi;`

Comment: Perfect! @Kamal Nayan

Comment: You have to escape the dot.